# C#.NET: How do I create a new instance of a class based solely on a "Type" object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object, types

Example:

```
public static System.Object CreateInstance ( System.Type t )
{
    // return t.<CreateNewObject>;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Instantiate an object with a runtime-determined type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981330/c-instantiate-an-object-with-a-runtime-determined-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`Activator.CreateInstance(t)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)