# How to create/instantiate an object of 'Type'

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to iterate through types in an assembly and if a type is a subclass of a specified interface, I want to create an object of the type and add it to a list like so:

```
var tasks = new List<IScheduledTask>();

foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IScheduledTask)))
    {
        tasks.Add(new t());
    }
}
```

Obviously this above does not work. How can you achieve what I am seeking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance` is what you're after.

```
var tasks = new List<IScheduledTask>();
foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IScheduledTask)))
    {
        tasks.Add((IScheduledTask)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a list of objects of type `Object` will it not?

Comment: No, the object will be of type T, you just need to cast it.

Comment: @abe-miessler to cast it: `tasks.Add((IScheduledTask)Activator.CreateInstance(t));`

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking he wanted to create an instance of the class that inherits from the interface.  If he wanted to do that, would it be possible?

Comment: @Abe-Miessler, that is what `CreateInstance` is doing here.  The type given to it is the implementing type, not the interface-type itself.  You cast to `IScheduledTask` because you have to in order to put it on your list.

Comment: But doesn't CreateInstance return an object of type `Object`?

Comment: @abe-miessler that's the signature of the method but it's "really" returning an instance of the type it is given.  Remember that everything inherits from `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method:

```
ObjectType instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

Answer (score 1):

This previous question may help
[Instantiate an object with a runtime-determined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981330/c-instantiate-an-object-with-a-runtime-determined-type)

It uses `Activator.CreateInstance`

Answer (score 1):

```
Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

will do the trick.

Be careful though, the class you want to instanciate must have a public constructor with no argument for it to work.