# compare object to class

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm trying to compare a class type passed through as an object to the class type on the other side where the method is.

How can I do this?

I have this so far.

The one side:

```
TechToday techToday = new TechToday();
SoftwareRevolution softwareRevolution = new SoftwareRevolution();

Subcriber s1 = new Subcriber();
s1.Subcribe(techToday);
s1.Subcribe(softwareRevolution);
```

The other side:

```
class Subcriber
{
    TechToday tt = new TechToday();
    SoftwareRevolution sr = new SoftwareRevolution();

    public void Subcribe(Object s)
    {
        if(s==tt)
            new ConsoleObserver(s);
        else                
            new ConsoleOutput(s);

    }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: Instead of `if (s == tt)` do `if (s is TechToday) { new ConsoleObserver (s as TechToday); }`

Comment: @RufusL the code is confusing, I think you are likely right.

Comment: @maccettura The method only handles a single subscription at a time. It must do this by receiving a single “object” as its parameter and then determining whether this object is a classic or events subject.

I'm still fairly new to this pattern of code so its trial and error for me

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. The created objects (ConsoleObserver and ConsoleOutput) will go out of scope when `Subscribe` returns ... And what is it: Do you want to compare Types or instances ?

Comment: @Cleaven I still think you are way better off using an overload

Comment: @maccettura I'm following instructions of the assignment

Comment: What _are_ the "instructions of the assignment" ?

Comment: @Cleaven I might suggest finding a new course then, this is not how you would normally handle this in the real world

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981330/instantiate-an-object-with-a-runtime-determined-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `is` operator to check if object is of that particular type like:

```
if(s is TechToday)
        new ConsoleObserver(s);
```

or you can do something like:

```
if(s.GetType() == typeof(TechToday))
```

if you are looking to do equality of objects then you will need to check first the type of it and then cast the reference to that specific type and then check for equality something like:

```
if(s is TechToday)
{
   TechToday tt2 = s as TechToday;
   if(tt2 == tt)
       new ConsoleObserver(tt2);
}
```

or you could also do it like:

```
TechToday tt2 = s as TechToday;
if(tt2 == tt)
    new ConsoleObserver(tt2);
```

Another option is using the new feature of C# 7 pattern matching :

```
if (s is TechToday tt2)
{
   if(tt2 == tt)
      new ConsoleObserver(tt2);
}
```

Comment: By the way `if(s is TechToday) {   TechToday tt2 = s as TechToday` is overkill, you could use `TechToday tt2 = s as TechToday; if (tt2 != null)...` or pattern matching of course

Comment: yes @vc74 and we don't event need null check if comparison is intended, it would return false if either is null

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use overloads if possible:

```
class Subcriber
{
    public void Subcribe(TechToday s)
    {
        new ConsoleObserver(s);
    }

    public void Subcribe(SoftwareRevolution s)
    {               
        new ConsoleOutput(s);
    }

}
```

If you have to stay with `object` in the signature of `Subscribe`, you probably want to use something along

```
if( s is TechToday ) { new ConsoleObserver(s); }
```

But **after all, this does not make much sense**, because as is, the created objects will go out of scope immediately after leaving `Subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the is operator:

```
class Subcriber
{
    public void Subcribe(Object s)
    {
        if(s is TechToday)
            new ConsoleObserver(s);
        else                
            new ConsoleOutput(s);

    }
}
```

However using "as" might be better:

```
class Subcriber
{
    public void Subcribe(Object s)
    {
        var tt = s as TechToday; 
        if(tt!=null)
           // unlike above 
           // value passed to ConsoleObserver is TechToday
           // casted already

            new ConsoleObserver(tt); 
        else                
            new ConsoleOutput(s);
    }
}
```