# Instantiate a reflected delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

I have a type variable

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

...

var validateFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(someVariableType, typeof(bool));
```

Now I check if `someVariableType` follows a convention,

```
var validateOfType = someVariableType
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .SingleOrDefault(mi =>
        {
            if (mi.Name != "Validate" || mi.ReturnType != typeof(bool))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var parameters = mi.GetParameters();
            return parameters.Length == 0;
        });
```

then depending on the check

```
object validateFunc;
if (validateOfType == null)
{
    validateFunc = // some noop func that returns true.
    // e.g.  _ => true;
}
else
{
    validateFunc = // a delegate that calls the conventional validate
    // e.g.  someVariable => someVariable.Validate();
}
```

instantiate an instance of the delegate type.

Can you help me do that, how can I instantiate `validateFuncType`, that calls the conventional implementation, if it exists?

Comment: BTW: I find it a good practice to prevent using var / always use explicit types. For readability purposes.

Comment: for a protracted debate on `var` you could start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is never going to work until the delegate type matches the rest of the code.  Which goes hunting for a method with no arguments, so it needs to be `Func<>` instead of `Func<,>`.  Or easier yet, just `typeof(Func<bool>)`.

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_):

```
var alwaysReturnTrueMethodInfo = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("AlwaysReturnTrue").MakeGenericMethod(someVariableType);
Delegate validateFunc;
if (validateOfType == null)
{
    validateFunc = Delegate.CreateDelegate(validateFuncType, alwaysReturnTrueMethodInfo);
}
else
{
    validateFunc = Delegate.CreateDelegate(validateFuncType, validateOfType);
}
```

where `AlwaysReturnTrue` is a helper static method declared like this:

```
public static bool AlwaysReturnTrue<T>(T t) { return true }
```

Comment: You understand correctly, I made a `bool CallByConventionValidate(dynamic target) { return target.Validate(); }` which seems nasty but also works.

Comment: It was useful, and I learned some good stuff from it but, after noticing the input parameters to `Func<>` are contravariant, I did [something that required less code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054000/659190). I'm still not sure what the best answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by:

```
// create an object of the type
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(validateFuncType);
```

And you'll get an instance of validateFuncType in obj.

Another way is to use reflection:

```
// get public constructors
var ctors = validateFuncType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);

// invoke the first public constructor with no parameters.
var obj = ctors[0].Invoke(new object[] { });
```

This was taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981344/468910). And because of that this question (and answer) might be marked as duplicate.

Comment: but how do I make one that does `_ => true;` and another that does `t => t.Validate();` ?

Comment: Your question is: "how can I instantiate validateFuncType"? That's what I answered. If you want specific (Interface) methods of the type instantiated you need to cast it to a more specific type then "just" Object.Is there a common INterface or base class perhaps for types with the Validate method and return types != bool? The cast the created object to the interface or base class.

Comment: I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, after noticing that input parameters for `Func<>` are contravariant.

```
object validateFunc = validateOfType != null
                ? config => (bool)validateOfType.Invoke(config, new object[0])
                : new Func<object, bool>(_ => true);
```

I'm not sure if this is better than [@Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57038439/659190)