# how to pass a string value to a type of expression?

Tags: c#

```
public void Invoke(string methodname)
{
    string funcname=methodname.Split('.')[1];

    //funcname contains the value of CustomerController
    Type type = typeof(funcname);

    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(funcname);
    CustomerController c = new CustomerController();
    string result = (string)method.Invoke(c, null);
}
```

In this I need to pass a string value to a `typeof` expression which is a class name. But I’m getting an compile time error. In the above code

```
Type type = typeof(funcname);
```

Here funcname contains the value `"CustomerController"`. If I replace it with the below line it works fine.

```
Type type = typeof(CustomerController);
```

How can I pass a string value to a `typeof` expression?

Comment: Your are invoking a method of `CustomerController`, So it should be `typeof(CustomerController)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
Type.GetType(className);
```

You have to give full class name. If class is defined in another assembly you also need to specify name of that assembly name.

```
Type.GetType("Name.Space.ClassName");
Type.GetType("Name.Space.ClassName, OtherAssemblyName");
```

If it is a nested class you can specify its name with a `+`

```
Type.GetType("Name.Space.ClassName+NestedClassName, OtherAssemblyName");
```

Comment: How did you use it and what is the name and namespace of your class?

Comment: i tried like this.    methoname= "UserController.AddUser"; Type type =Type.GetType(methoname);

Comment: It seems like you are specifying `ClassName.MethodName` not `NameSpace.ClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can’t.

The `typeof` takes a type, not a string containing the type name. To get the type from a string, you can use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7aahsb8.aspx) with a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on other answers.

If your argument is "SomeClass.SomeMethod"

Then you want to use `Type.GetType("SomeClass")` but for that to work you need the namespace, as mentioned by Adil

Then you use

```
myType.GetMethod("SomeMethod");
```

Then you could create an instance of it and call the method.
You might cut a few steps out with Activator.CreateInstance

[Get a new object instance from a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)