# String Value to Variable

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is scenario

```
string dataTypeName = "Employee";
```

where Employee is class and i want to make an object of it.

```
Type EmployeeObject = Type.GetType(dataTypeName);
```

Now i want to instantiate an object of Employee like this

```
EmployeeObject emp1 = new Employee();
```

Is it Possible. But this method is not working. I don't have strong idea of Reflection. Please Guide me.

Comment: What is the value of - `typeof(Employee).AssemblyQualifiedName`? What is the need to get `EmployeeObject` from the name, and then instansiate it with a literal type anyway - why not just use the literal type in the first place?

Comment: @LukeHennerley Value: Reflection.Employee, Reflection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type

Answer (score 5):

[CreateObjectfromassemblynameandclassname](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Reflection/CreateObjectfromassemblynameandclassname.htm)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;


public class Reflection
{

    public static T CreateObject<T>(string assemblyName, string className)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        return (T)assembly.CreateInstance(className);
    }
}
```