# Creating objects with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, null-object-pattern

I'm trying to write a `NullObject` creation method, where I pass in a class name that implements an `ICreateEmptyInstance` interface (that is empty) and it walks it's properties looking for other classes that implement `ICreateEmptyInstance` and will create "Null" instances of those.

```
public interface ICreateEmptyInstance { }

public static class NullObject
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : ICreateEmptyInstance, new()
    {
        var instance = new T();

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties.Where(property => typeof(ICreateEmptyInstance).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)))
        {
            var propertyInstance = NullObject.Create<property.PropertyType>();
            property.SetValue(instance, propertyInstance);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

I should be able to call it with this

```
var myEmptyClass = NullObject.Create<MyClass>();
```

Where I'm having issues is inside of the foreach loop, with this line

```
var propertyInstance = NullObject.Create<property.PropertyType>();
```

...obviously that doesn't work, but how can I accomplish creating a "null object" to assign to the instance I'm currently creating.

EDIT:
And what about generics?? I'd like empty instances created

```
  foreach (var property in properties.Where(property => property.GetType().IsGenericType))
  {
       var propertyInstance = Enumerable.Empty<>(); //TODO: how do I get the type for here?
       property.SetValue(instance, propertyInstance);
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a new object instance from a Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a non-generic method and use it:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : ICreateEmptyInstance, new()
{
    return (T) Create(typeof (T));
}

private static object Create(Type type)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties.Where(property => typeof(ICreateEmptyInstance).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)))
    {
        var propertyInstance = NullObject.Create(property.PropertyType);
        property.SetValue(instance, propertyInstance);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: That looks good, but I got a stack overflow exception!  the loop was creating the wrong type I think, now to test this out.

Comment: what about collections? any thoughts on how to ensure the instance has it's list properties created with empty lists?

Comment: What exactly do you want, create an empty collection for the type that implements the `ICreateEmptyInstance` interface?

Comment: No, when I'm creating `instance` and setting it's properties that implement `ICreateEmptyInstance` I also want to set any properties that are collections or arrays to contain empty collections.