# creating instance of a type dynamically

Tags: c#

Let's say I have this code:

```
object abc;
abc = typeof(myclass);
```

So, I'd like to do something like this

```
var newobject = GetTheValueTypeAndCreateTheInstance(abc);
```

and newobject is instance of myclass.

If I do `abc = typeof(mycar)`, newobject is instance of mycar

Having abc variable, how do I create instance of `myclass` ? note that it could be any other class. Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type

Comment: thanks for the help. because abc is type of object, the activator will create a new object, not instance of myclass.

Comment: Then would `object abc = new myclass();` not work?

Comment: Have a look at `Activator` class, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it could be typeof(myclass), or typeof(myotherclass), etc.. if abc contains the value typeof(myclass), I want to create a new instance of myclass in another variable. if it's myotherclass, I want to create a new instance of myotherclass in another variable

Comment: So you want the `Activator` class: `public void DoSomething(Type type) { object abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type); /* other code */ }`

Comment: the Type is dynamic. I wouldn't know when the user will pass carclass, or fruitclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it

```
object ABC = typeof(System.Text.StringBuilder);
dynamic _ABC = ABC;
var Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(_ABC.UnderlyingSystemType);
```