# Alternative way to return concrete objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function which takes an object parameter say entity and returns concrete objects like below. The concrete objects inherits from IEntity.

```
        public IEntity GetEntity(object entity) 
        {
            if(entity is A) { .... return new Customer(); }
            else if(entity is B) {... return new Invoice(); }
            .......
        }
```

This obviously works but I was wondering if this is the best approach or is there any other alternative and recommended way from architecture perspective?

Thanks!

Comment: To determine the proper approach, you need to explain why you have this method in the first place.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal `Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType());` can be more accurate way to write above code.

Comment: Why do you even need this?  I suspect the architectural concern is what drove the need for this method, not the method itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a new object instance from a Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The same entity names of different namespaces might have created the confusion here. I've edited the code now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics:

```
public IEntity GetEntity<T>(T entity)
    where T : IEntity, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: Wheher this is or isn't a valid approach depends on how OP calls this code. That's why this question is currently too broad and should not be answered; I can think of twenty possible approaches, all which can or cannot be relevant to OP - we need more input.

Comment: If the consuming code only knows that the type is an `object` then wouldn't this result in a new instance of `Object`?

Comment: @David no, you cannot call this with an `object` reference, because `object !: IEntity`.

Comment: @tchelidze don't suggest [edits like that](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10866386). You're deviating from what OP tried to say in their answer. If you think the answer is incorrect, post a comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, i'll take into account.

Comment: Please refer edited code. Sorry for confusion.