# Load Assembly and create class using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I could not find a way of creating a class object from given type and assembly definition using reflection. 
For my case, I have a string containing class and assembly name and need to create the object:

```
string str = "My.Assembly.Namesapce.MyClass, My.Assembly.Namesapce, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84474dc3c6524430";
var objClass = --SOME CODE TO USE  STR AND CREATE MyClass--
```

I have tried to split and create class but that is not very good way of doing it.

Comment: The Class you are looking for is called Activator. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/755/4369295)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an instance of a class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: Random question: is it possible that it isn't working because of the `My.Assembly.Namesapce` typo? (twice)

Comment: @MarcGravell No - that will be his next problem ;-) He's definitely looking for the code to actually convert a string to an instance - hence the `--SOME CODE TO USE  STR AND CREATE MyClass--` comment.

Comment: Is the `MyClass` type in the `MyClass objClass` declaration the same `MyClass` as is mentioned in the string? If so then why do you even need reflection? Simply do `MyClass objClass = new MyClass(...);` ?

Comment: I have changed `MyClass` to `var`. The assembly already exists in solution and I'm able to create object of  `MyClass` separately but in a scenario the string from database is coming and the object generated may or may not be of type `MyClass` (which I will test in next statement in code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1) Convert your string `str` into a type, and
2) Create an instance of that type.

```
string typeString = "My.Assembly.Namesapce.MyClass, My.Assembly.Namesapce, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84474dc3c6524430";

// Get a reference to the type.
Type theType = Type.GetType(typeString, true, false);

// Create an instance of that type.
MyClass  theInstance = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

Comment: You can also construct an instance by calling the constructor: `object theInstance = theType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null)`, but note that it isn't typical that you write your code with a typed variable like that, if you already have the type, there's no need for the reflection so most likely either `object` or some interface type that is expected to be implemented by the class goes in place of `MyClass` when declaring `theInstance`.

Comment: @Lasse To be honest, I generally use an IoC container to create an instance, which can make managing constructor arguments much easier (as you don't need to know them a-priori, or assume a no-arg constructor).

Comment: Yes, so do I, just in the context of this question that's probably overkill :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Type type = Type.GetType(str);
object objClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

however, to do anything useful with the object you will have to use a common interface / base-class, reflection, or `dynamic`.

Note: if you can type the variable as `MyClass objClass`, then the simpler version is of course:

```
MyClass objClass = new MyClass();
```