# c# - Invoke method with parameters

Tags: c#

How can I invoke a method with parameters?

I have this:

```
List<String> methods = new List<String>(new List<String>{ "first", "second" });
int number = 4;
String text = "Hi";
bool isTrue = false;
```

And want to invoke the method like this:

```
if (isTrue)
    Invoke(methods[0], number);
else if (!isTrue)
    Invoke(methods[1], { number, text });
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't get the question, are you looking for some kind of reflection?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PeterBons It is possible he just wants a new method right? I'm not sure how `Invoke` works, but I think its used in the wrong way here. I think a standard method call would work fine. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I am assuming that you are trying to call a method by it's name, and that that method has parameters. Assuming also that:

- You have an object called `obj` that is of type `YourObject`
- `YourObject` contains public, non-static methods named `first` and `second`

then you should be able to use the following:

```
if (isTrue)
    typeof(YourObject).GetMethod(methods[0]).Invoke(obj, new[] { number });
else if (!isTrue)
    typeof(YourObject).GetMethod(methods[1]).Invoke(obj, new[] { number, text });
```

Comment: Can you write me how I can create object obj?

Comment: Assuming you're not in a position to do var obj = new YourObject(), I would refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's something wrong with the answer, please can you explain what it is, or correct the answer?

Comment: I don't give you downvote. And can I asign var obj = new YourObject(); without creating new one?

Comment: @MineGame159 I wasn't accusing you of downvoting - I can't tell who has downvoted, but someone has. As far as your last comment is concerned, I'm not sure what you mean. As I say, it's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to do, so it's difficult to give further advice. If you could add some more specifics to your question, that would help. new YourObject() *will* create a new object. Or are you asking if you need to create the class? If so, then yes.

Comment: @bornfromanegg stumbled upon this, gave u an upvote to negate the downvote u don't deserve