# Type.GetType("namespace.classname, assemblyname") returns null, in a solution with main project and two class library projects

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reflection, app-config

So I have a visual studio solution with 3 projects in it:

1. A class library BLL project that contains EmployeeBLL.cs
2. A second class library DAL project that has MemoryProvider.cs
3. A WPF project, that has EmployeeViewModel.cs and an app.config file

***Code:***

- **App.config - appsettings**

  *add key="EmployeeMemoryProvider" value="EmployeeMemoryProvider.MemoryProvider,EmployeeMemoryProvider"*
- **EmployeeViewModel.cs - constructor:**

  ```
  public EmployeeViewModel()
  {
      var configString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmployeeMemoryProvider"];
      _employeeBLL = new EmployeeBLL(configString);
      var employeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(_employeeBLL.GetAllEmployess());
  }
  ```

  }
- **EmployeeBLL.cs, constructor:**

  ```
  public EmployeeBLL(string configString)
  {
      var providerType = Type.GetType(configString);
      _employeeProvider = (IEmployeeProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(providerType);
  }
  ```

***Goal:*** I want to get the type of the string from the App.config, which the string is first obtained in *EmployeeViewModel.cs* as *configString* then passed into the constructor of *EmployeeBLL.cs* and finally use the *Type.GetType(configString)* to get the type of *configString*

**Problem**: the *providerType* returns null, even though the assembly name and namespace of the DAL project are both *EmployeeMemoryProvider*.

Can anyone shed some light? Is it because I missed a space after the comma in *"EmployeeMemoryProvider.MemoryProvider,EmployeeMemoryProvider"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)

Comment: Are project referenced or assembly for MemoryProvider is copied into your bin folder? What is namespace for MemoryProvider ?

Comment: This is really a dup of how to get a new object instance from a Type. You can see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type which has quick example and links to Microsoft docs on how to use Activator. Which will explain what it needs as you can bypass the calling to a Type. However you will still need a properly formatted type string which these docs in that question should help with.

Comment: @tykovec the namespace for MemoryProvider is EmployeeMemoryProvider, and the WPF project does not have a reference to the project assembly for MemoryProvider

Comment: I think you need to load assembly EmployeeMemoryProvider with Assembly.LoadFrom / Assembly.LoadFile, afterwards should Type.GetType working.