# How to return the correct type of an inherited type from a method in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Here below is what I'm trying to achieve. It is easier to show with a code snippet.

```
abstract class MyBaseType {}

class MyType1: MyBaseType() {}

class MyType2: MyBaseType() {}

class MyType3: MyBaseType() {}

public class Utils()
{
    public XXXX IdentifyCorrectType()
    {
        var identifyingCondition = GetCorrectType();// returns 1,2,3...
        switch(identifyingCondition)
        {
            case 1:
                return typeof(MyType1);break;
            case 2:
                return typeof(MyType2);break;
            case 3:
                return typeof(MyType3);break;
        }
    }
}
```

What should be written in place of **XXXX** in the declaration of ***IdentifyCorrectType*** method for this code to compile? The return value is used somewhere else to instantiate that type, and so only the correct type needs to be returned from this method.

PS: Returning objects of desired classes(eg. `new MyType2()`) instead of types is not possible due to class dependencies which are not always available everywhere.

Comment: So your question is about how to use a `System.Type`.  [Edit] to clarify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: I need to instantiate that type in the consuming code. And like I mentioned in PS, the type itself cannot be instantiated from within the *Utils* class as the dependencies are not available.

Comment: or [How to create a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/how-to-create-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type) depending on what your actually asking which isn't clear

Comment: I suspect this may be (part of) a broken approach to try to avoid specifying type parameters using compile-time types when consuming generics. It never ends well

Comment: And why do you need `GetCorrectType` to return a number? Wouldn't it be simpler to just return `Type` from that method, instead of this extra method with the case statement? Also, the `break;` are redunrant, since you are already using `return` in each `case`.

Comment: That doesn't seem very oop and it sure as hell ain't generics. well, at least one out of three tags is correct...

Comment: Your PS seems to me like a - often used but allmost allways whrong - approach to prevent circular dependencies. You should re-think your class-design.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this? Take a step back, and show a more complete sample showing how you think this will help you. In other words, what does the code _consuming_ `IdentifyCorrectType` look like?

Comment: Why should it fail? Did you try it out? `Activatator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyType1))` will create an identical instance as if you´d return the type of `MyType1` from your method and call `CreateInstance` with it.

Comment: `public MyBaseType IdentifyCorrectType() { ... return (new MyType1()); ... }` or something like that. I mean, instantiate your object in the switch case, since you have access to the types in that method

Comment: @mjwills Briefly, the context is this. This is a Xamarin.Forms project, using MVVM  and I need to decide which screen to show first depending on certain conditions which I check inside platform-specific codes. If the correct type is returned,I can then initialize that object in after Xamarin.Forms is completed loaded and ready.

Comment: @Cid Like mentioned in PS, returning *new MyType1()* is not possible because the dependencies are not available yet at the point where I'm trying to identify the correct types.

Comment: `because the dependencies are not available yet at the point where I'm trying to identify the correct types.` I'd suggest using a IoC container, and asking for the object from the IoC container. It is then the IoC container's problem to manage the dependencies.

Comment: @mjwills Not arguing but the problem is not with IoC even with dependencies supplied.Those dependencies are platform dependent which is not ready yet. The constructor would not execute successfully.

Comment: You have two options here. Either have this method return an **instance** of the type. IoC is the easiest way to do that. Or have it return a `Type`. The latter sounds appealing - but it isn't. So, you have the `Type`. Now, you need to instantitate it. So you need **more** code to determine the dependencies of that `Type` so you can call the constructor. And some of those dependencies have dependencies of their own. etc etc Now, you can do it that way - but if you do you basically just **built your own IoC container**. So the two options are the same - except the latter option is harder!

Comment: @mjwills YES. So, what do I do ? :)

Comment: You use an IoC container. Register `MyType1` etc with the container. Then resolve the instance from the container. The complexity of your code sample and the way you are describing the problem is obscuring the simplicity of your problem - you want a new to get instances of objects with their dependencies ready to go. That is what IoC is great at.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1:**
As per `@Cid`, the better approach as per the comments should be:

```
public MyBaseType IdentifyCorrectType()
    {
        var identifyingCondition = GetCorrectType();// returns 1,2,3...
        switch (identifyingCondition)
        {
            case 1:
                return new MyType1();
            case 2:
                return new MyType2();
            case 3:
                return new MyType3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

---

You can use [Type class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the output of IdentifyCorrectType method:

```
public Type IdentifyCorrectType()
{
    var identifyingCondition = GetCorrectType();// returns 1,2,3...
    switch(identifyingCondition)
    {
        case 1:
            return typeof(MyType1);
        case 2:
            return typeof(MyType2);
        case 3:
            return typeof(MyType3);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cid Like mentioned in PS, returning new MyType1() is not possible because the dependencies are not available yet at the point where I'm trying to identify the correct types. This is a Xamarin.Forms project, using MVVM and I need to decide which screen to show first depending on certain conditions which I check inside platform-specific codes. If the correct type is returned,I can then initialize that object in consuming code *after Xamarin.Forms is completed loaded and ready*.

Comment: @Cid - Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @iSahilSharma yes, but I removed my answer, since this wasn't what OP was looking for