# How do I dynamically add an existing form to a collection by its name

Tags: c#

I am trying to add some existing forms to a collection dynamically.

The below code will iterate through the assemblies and find any forms (hope I got that right).  If a form matches part of the form name, I wanted to add it to the collection.  I, of course, could do this explicitly in code by Forms.add(new frm_Form1).  I wanted to do it this way so I don't forget to add a form (I guess I'm being kind of lazy).

```
    List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>();

    private void addForms()
    {
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly a in assemblies)
        {
            Type[] types = a.GetTypes();

            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
                {
                    if (t.Name.Substring(0, 4).ToLower() == "frm_")
                    {
                        // How to add the form (found in the for loop) to the Forms collection.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you are loking for types - not instances. When you find one, and it is your goal, you could use [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8) to create an instance of your type, and than add it to your collection. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/how-to-create-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type) is an example of Activator usage.

```
Form instance = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Forms.Add(instance);
```

Comment: and you might have multiple instances of that form, for example