DRY - Derived class with static methods
In Unity C#, I have a base class Baker, it's derived from ScriptableObject, and I'm deriving from it CakeBaker, BreadBaker, PieBaker.
ScriptableObjects can only be created statically, using CreateAsset()
This leads me to the situation where each of my bakers now contain an identical method CreateBaker(), with the only difference being the Type.
statics and generics don't mix, and a static method works on the class it's declared in, not any class derived from it.
I thought about C/C++ style Macros, but AFAICS there's no equivalent in C#.
How do I avoid repeating myself (and all that it entails) in this situation?
it's a small method, and there are currently not too many bakers, so I've just copied the method and gotten on with it, but I wondered if the hive mind would have a better idea.
private static string assetPath => "Assets/PieBakerAsset.asset";

public static void CreateAsset(bool updateAssetDatabase = true)
{
    var instance = CreateInstance();
    // Save the newly created instance to the AssetDatabase if it does not exist
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(instance, assetPath);
    if (updateAssetDatabase)
    {
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}

public static Baker CreateInstance()
{
    return CreateInstance<PieBaker>();
}


It is hard to understand what you want to achieve as a result. You have no need to add those CreateAsset methods, as it can be made by using CreateAssetMenu attribute

There's an interesting pattern here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644378/create-dynamic-instance-from-a-dictionary-of-types
The static method in the base class can't possibly know about the subclass instance, there will "some" repetition I think.

@Morion It is hard to understand what you want to achieve as a result. You have no need to add those CreateAsset methods, as it can be made by using CreateAssetMenu attribute

This is part of an automation. The assets are created during the pre-build process
@PatriceGagnon this is a good thought. it's much closer to the factory idea that I'm going for.

You can try to do something like the following, by writing the CreateAsset() function for the Baker class to allow for generic types:
public static T CreateAsset<T>(string assetPath, bool updateAssetDatabase = true) where T : ScriptableObject
    {
        T instance = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>();
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(instance, assetPath);
        if (updateAssetDatabase)
        {
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
            AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        }
        return instance;
    }

Then, when you want to create an instance of a CakeBaker, for example, you could do the following, assuming CakeBaker inherits from the Baker class:
CakeBaker newCakeBaker = Baker.CreateAsset<CakeBaker>("Assets/NewCakeBaker.asset");


hmm, the reason I didn't do this was that the path is a member of the derived class (also static because it has to be so it can be used by the static method). I'll update the original question to reflect this.
possibly I can just have a defs file containing these...
